# Self Signed RSA Certificate export private key parameters exception in .NET Core 3.1 [Windows 10 Pro OS]

Tags: rsa, x509certificate2, encryption-asymmetric, .net-core-3.1, windows-10-desktop

I have created a self signed RSA certificate and stored the Private key as .pfx file. Then from my .Net Core 3.1 code i'm trying to instantiate the X509Certificate2 object with the .pfx file. The X509Certificate2 instance is created successfully but from the code "certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportParameters(true)" getting an exception as "The requested operation is not supported".

```
X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyData, _privateKeyPwd, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
RSAParameters rSAParameters = certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportParameters(true);
```

Exception:
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'The requested operation is not supported'.

Can you please help me.

Edit: The rSAParameters will be used to decrypt an encrypted symmetric key.

```
rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rSAParameters);
byte[] encryptedSymmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(dataKey);
// Decrypt using OAEP padding.
byte[] decryptedSymmetricKey = rsaProvider.Decrypt(encryptedSymmetricKey, fOAEP: true);
```

Comment: for what purpose you want to export parameters?

Comment: @Crypt32 I need to perform the operation "RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rSAParameters);"

Comment: for what purpose you need `RSACryptoServiceProvider`? Can you show your code where you are going to use it?

Comment: @Crypt32 I have updated the question with the code snippets.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thanks! I found my mistake. I had tried with the same RSA Decrypt() method version you mentioned but using the "RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256" only.

Comment: I believe, legacy `RSACryptoServiceProvider` defaults to OAEP SHA1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see something like `rsaKey.ExportParameters(true)`, in 99.999% cases this indicates a bad design/patern in code.

In fact, you don't need to export and re-import parameters, do it simply:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyData, _privateKeyPwd, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
RSA privateKey = certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey();
// decrypt data
byte[] decryptedSymmetricKey = privateKey.Decrypt(encryptedSymmetricKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
```

Comment: True, but *sometimes* you really do want to export the private parameters/key. I'm glad you solved the OP's problem, but it would be nice if you'd tackled the root cause of *why* calling `GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportParameters(true)` was throwing.

Comment: In a given case it was an XY problem, so don't need to solve irrelevant problems. If you have specific issue, start your own thread.